# python 2.7 windows7, stringIO, getvalue(), error 6

Tags: python-2.7, encoding

python 2.7  windows7,   when I run a program, it shows error6 of stringIO, getvalue() function,

how to fix that?

```
try
```

`blablabla(very long program, it could function well before I add some 
            hardware control function)`

`except Exception as e:

```
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()

        a = StringIO()
        traceback.print_tb(exc_traceback, limit=1, file=a)
        error_msg = a.getvalue()
        a.close()
```

`

Comment: What is the code, what is the input, what is the error message?

Comment: Better make a [mcve]. After repairing your code and runnig it, I get nothing strange at all.

Comment: I used Python 3, actually, for my test. When I use Python 2, I get "TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'" in `print_tb`, which I can't explain, but nothing like what you say.

Comment: I have found the detail of the error:File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 382, in __init__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 505, in _get_handles
WindowsError: [Error 6] 
16:36:08: Unexpected Error Occurred: